# error Nil default argument value of cannot be converted to type 'NSLayoutFormatOptions'

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I have upgraded to swift 2 and this function has created a headache for me.

This is causing the error when trying to run the app. I have no idea how to fix this as I'm trying to upgrade it to swift 2. I have done an extensive search but not able to remedy the code.  The error occurs on :  `NSLayoutFormatOptions = nil` when creating the function.

```
internal extension UIView {

    func addConstraints(format format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions = nil, metrics: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, views: [String: UIView]) {
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: options, metrics: metrics, views: views))
    }

    func addUniversalConstraints(format format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions = nil, metrics: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, views: [String: UIView]) {
        addConstraints(format: "H:\(format)", options: options, metrics: metrics, views: views)
        addConstraints(format: "V:\(format)", options: options, metrics: metrics, views: views)
    }

}
```

Thank you if you can help. :)

Yours Sincerely
Gerard Grundy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `options` parameter is not declared as Optional, so you can't set a default value of `nil`.

Either make `options` an Optional:

```
func addConstraints(format format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions? = nil, metrics: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, views: [String: UIView])
```

or remove `= nil` from the signature:

```
func addConstraints(format format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions, metrics: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, views: [String: UIView])
```

Comment: ok that has helped though now I'm getting an error here:  public func selectRowAtIndex(index: Index) {
  selectedRowIndex = index
  
  tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(
   NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0),
   animated: false,
   scrollPosition: .Middle)
 }

Comment: This is an entirely different question and I have no idea how to help you about it... I suggest you post a new question with details about it so you can get this new question resolved by someone else.

Comment: by setting the scrollPosition: .Middle to scrollPosition: .None solved the problem as a work around